# stack and heap diagram of method that is assigned to reference variable

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

How could we draw the stack and heap diagram of following code:

```
Ball b1;
Ball b2 = new Ball();
Ball b3 = new Ball();
b1= doThing();
b3 = doThings();
```

I know call methed (e.g doThing()) will be in stack. how relate b1 (which is in stack to doThing()). should we create an object in heap for them?

Answer (score 1):

All java-ojbect created in heap. If doThing() instantiate Ball then we should create an object in heap for them on diagram.

Comment: so doThing() will link to Ball or b1?

Comment: Edit: so doThing() will link to Ball, or b1 will link to Ball?

Comment: Please, see on this image: http://vikashazrati.files.wordpress.com/2007/10/stacknheap.png